# Capturar mudança TextField do JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Tem algum evento que captura cada mudança que ocorre em um TextField do JAvaFX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pergunta um pouco genérica pois são várias as propriedades do [TextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html) que podem ser observadas pelo programador. Olhando a documentação temos:

Propriedades do herdadas do TextInputControl (São as principais):

[anchor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#anchorProperty), [caretPosition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#caretPositionProperty), [editable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#editableProperty), [font](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#fontProperty), [length](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#lengthProperty), [promptText](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#promptTextProperty), [redoable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#redoableProperty), [selectedText](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#selectedTextProperty), [selection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#selectionProperty), [textFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#textFormatterProperty), [text](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#textProperty), [undoable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#undoableProperty)

Todas essas propriedades possuem métodos com a palavra Property ao final (ex.: `textProperty()`). Além dos métodos supracitados temos ainda 104 propriedades que podem ser observadas.

Vou falar das propriedades que normalmente são tratadas, o que fazem e como se deve capturar as mudanças.

**textProperty()**: Acredito que é a mais comum. Essa propriedade envolve o texto inserido/apagado no componente.

```
textfield.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String oldValue, String newValue) {
        // oldValue = Texto anterior a edição
        // newValue = Texto atual
        System.out.println(newValue);
    }
});

// Código acima usando lambdas
text.textProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String oldValue, String newValue) -> {
    System.out.println(newValue);
});
```

**Obs.:** Usamos normalmente o [ChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html) (como o nome indica ele captura mudanças) mas existe a opção de usar um [InvalidationListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/InvalidationListener.html) para notificar a entrada em um estado inválido.

**lengthProperty()**: Essa propriedade envolve o tamanho do texto do componente a medida que o usuário digita/apaga o conteúdo.

```
textfield.lengthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
         if(newValue.intValue() > 10)
             System.out.println("Texto muito longo");
    }
});

// Código acima usando lambdas
textfield.lengthProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {
   if(newValue.intValue() > 10)
       System.out.println("Texto muito longo");
});
```

Como já deve ter visto o código para capturar mudanças é semelhante entre as propriedades. Todavia, o TextField tem uma particularidade nesse quesito que é o TextFormatter. Com ele você tem a possibilidade de analisar uma mudança antes que ela seja efetivada (Apenas para java 8u40+)

```
textfield.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(change ->
    {
        if (change.getControlNewText().isEmpty()) {
            return change;
        }

        String text = change.getControlNewText();
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
            if(!Character.isDigit(text.charAt(i))){
                return null;
            }
        }

        return change;
    }));
```

Com os métodos getControlText() e getControlNewText() conseguimos pegar os texto atual e pós-edição (sem que a mudança tenha sido efetivada ainda). O código acima anula (return null) qualquer mudança que contenha em seu texto um elemento não numérico. Não vou entrar em detalhes de como usar o TextFormatter porque ele é muito amplo, mas você pode ver exemplos [aqui](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2991463/learn-java/javafx-improvements-in-java-se-8u40.html?page=4).

Answer (score 0):

Adicione um Listener no [textProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.TextProperty.html) de seu TextField:

```
textField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    System.out.println("Valor antigo = " + oldValue + ". Valor novo = " + newValue);
});
```